# How to check if form password field is empty in magento

Tags: php, magento

i want to check if Password field is empty then form will not update password in database otherwise update password

```
$userData = array('firstname' => $FirstName, 'lastname' => $LastName, 'username' => $Params['email'], 'email' => $Params['email'], 'password' => $Params['password']);
```

Please help to resolve this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if ($userData['password']) {
    // password is not empty. do whatever you want
 }
```

Or

```
 // just check `$Params`
 if ($Params['password'])
```

**Note:** - Look into coding standards,http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/, and enable a linter in your editor.